# How to Upgrade Web API to Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I got some information for upgrading MVC 4 and Web API to MVC 5 and Web API 2
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2
I followed the steps from that hyperlink.

For upgrading from Web API to Web API 2, in global.asax, change:
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); 
to
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

I am unable to find Configure() under GlobalConfiguration. Am I missing any reference here or am I supposed to include any definition or namespace?

Comment: Can it be that a namespace is missing? Might be if Configure is an extension method.

Comment: I have System.Web.Http; namespace for now. What else I should include.

Answer (score 0):

if you have :

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

at the top of your file, then check if your project is actually referencing MVC 5 / Web API 2 assemblies

Comment: Yes I do have using System.Web.Http; 
And I'm using Visual Studio 2013.
How to check whether it is referencing MVC 5 / Web API 2 assemblies?

Comment: if you are using Nuget, make sure the packages.config file contains version "5.1" for the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" entry....

Comment: yes I'm using Nuget and my packages.config also contains version "5.1.1" for Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi..Core.